# How to make a struct field containing an Arc writable?

Tags: rust, immutability, dereference, raw-pointer

I have a struct that somehow must be retrieved in the form of raw pointer.

```
pub struct BufferData {
    /// Memory map for pixel data
    pub map: Arc<Box<memmap::MmapMut>>,
    pub otherdata: i32,
}
```

I need to write into its `map` field, so I dereference the raw pointer into struct, then try to write into its data field. But, I got the following error.

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow immutable borrowed content `*map` as mutable
  --> examples/buffer.rs:34:5
   |
34 |     map[0] = 9;
   |     ^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

How do I make the `map` field mutable and writable?

The error is reproducible using the following code:

```
extern crate memmap;

use std::fs::File;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::boxed::Box;
use std::ops::Deref;

pub struct BufferData {
    /// Memory map for pixel data
    pub map: Arc<Box<memmap::MmapMut>>,
    pub otherdata: i32,
}

fn main() -> () {
    // Somewhere on other module
    let mut mmap = Arc::new(Box::new(unsafe {
        memmap::MmapMut::map_mut(&File::open("./shm").expect("file")).expect("MmapMut")
    }));
    let mut bfr = BufferData {
        map: mmap,
        otherdata: 0,
    };
    let ptr: *const _ = &bfr;

    // Here, I must receive and process a pointer
    let mut bdata: &BufferData = unsafe { &*(ptr as *const BufferData) };
    let mut map = bdata.map.deref().deref();

    // Problem lies here: need to write into it, so need to be mutable
    map[0] = 9;
}
```

Crate: `memmap = "0.6.2"`

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) or the [`rc` module](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc)? Have you tried a `Mutex`?

Comment: Eh? This "...you cannot generally obtain a mutable reference to something inside an Rc" part is it? Well, I'm not register that one! I'll try `Mutex` and answer myself then. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [@Shepmaster pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48614854/how-to-make-a-struct-field-acquired-by-dereferencing-a-raw-pointer-writable#comment84227253_48614854), `Arc` is immutable by design:

> Shared references in Rust disallow mutation by default, and `Arc` is no exception: you cannot generally obtain a mutable reference to something inside an `Arc`. If you need to mutate through an `Arc`, use `Mutex`, `RwLock`, or one of the `Atomic` types.

I added a `Mutex` to fix the problem:

```
pub struct BufferData {
    /// Memory map for pixel data
    pub map: Arc<Mutex<Box<memmap::MmapMut>>>,
    pub otherdata: i32,
}
```

To access the field, I need to lock it first. I added an additional block to automatically unlock the `Mutex` when the block is done:

```
{
    let mut map = bdata.map.lock().unwrap();
    map[0] = 9;
}
```